# Show an image of Dropbox

Tags: php, image, curl, header, dropbox

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init ("https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/Printable/game-of-thrones-poster1.jpg?oauth_consumer_key=3gg0ec7ju39cghr&oauth_token=pmrniz9qif7kbe3&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_signature=qcwg77mfetqr4zi%26l8l632jrmw3h80b&oauth_timestamp=1347451716&oauth_nonce=793902999f4dfae87ed757e1c6443f40&oauth_version=1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3');
$image=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
?>
```

With the above code, I want to display an image file on dropbox. But the picture does not display!

[image]

I'm using oauth information, dropbox located on a file (image, video, ..) I know how you view your? Saving to the server, I want to show through dropbox.

Comment: Have you tried removing *Content-type* header and see if an error is returned?

Comment: you are sending png headers for a jpg..

Comment: > Have you tried removing Content-type header and see if an error is returned?

I tried to delete the header. No return an error. A blank page is coming.